# When Did Nissan Globally Treat Electrical Corrosion Issues for the USDM?

Tags: electrical, nissan

I'm trying to figure out when Nissan addressed corroding electrical connections in their vehicles. Somewhere around the mid-to-late-90's maybe?

I've been told that the notorious electrical issues of earlier Nissan's where due to a lack of corrosion-proofing of the connectors, terminals, wiring, etc. and I am trying to research it further.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What’s a “USDM”?

Comment: United States Domestic Market. It implies that the vehicle was produced with the direct intention of sales in America. This is drastically different from JDM(Japanese Domestic Market), in that we have different emission laws, etc.

Comment: You will find several manufacturers were addressing corrosion issues : some of the engineers had a hard time persuading designers that electrolysis even existed let alone was relevant... And, yes I met some of them... I was banned from the next meeting after saying “but an 11 year old does this  (electrolysis) in physics at school” ... :) :) good way to get out of meetings...